# How do I get this navbar-brand centered on the navbar?

Tags: python, html, css, django

I have tried to get this `navbar-brand` item centered on the navbar but nothing has worked so far. Can someone help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Example page</title>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light mb-4 border">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'a_better_place:home' %}">
          A Better Place
        </a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
              <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'a_better_place:contact' %}">
                          Contact
                      </a>
                   </li>
              </ul>
          </div>
    </nav>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.6.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-KsvD1yqQ1/1+IA7gi3P0tyJcT3vR+NdBTt13hSJ2lnve8agRGXTTyNaBYmCR/Nwi" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-nsg8ua9HAw1y0W1btsyWgBklPnCUAFLuTMS2G72MMONqmOymq585AcH49TLBQObG" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using bootstrap framework

Comment: either you use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) or text-align

Comment: Can you show me how this would be written? I have tried text-align already and it did not work.

Comment: what is the bootstrap version ?

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `row` and `col` class:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Example page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light mb-4 border row">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="col-4"></div>
    <div class="col-4 text-center">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'a_better_place:home' %}">
            A Better Place
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'a_better_place:contact' %}">
                      Contact
                  </a>
               </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
</nav>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: mind specifying the bootstrap version you have used ?

Comment: The same that is in the question but works also with 4.6 and probably less recent ones (tested with 5.0.0-beta and 4.6.0)

Comment: and have you tested your code ? 'cause i did, and it did not give an answer to the post ... 
the `.navbar-brand` must be centered not sided to the right 
---
this is what your code look like : https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-roentgen-pthju

Comment: As you can read by the previous comments I tested it and you can see it working too by trying it in desktop mode. The question doesn't specify the screen resolution so keep calm, we are both here to help

Comment: Oh, my bad then

Answer (score 0):

The answer above works but it's setting only margins to left
the best option is to use .mx-auto sets margin on left and right of the horizontal axis

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light mb-4 border row">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="col-4"></div>
    <div class="col-4 text-center">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            A Better Place
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                      Contact
                  </a>
               </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
</nav>
```